# AES Encryption of Arabic characters - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, arabic

I have an encryption function that gets data and key, with inner iv and returns an encrypted string. I can encrypt every string that contains just English characters but not about Arabic. This is my function. Please help me to find the problem. Thanks

```
-(NSString*)Encrypt:(NSString*)data second:(NSString*)key
    {
        size_t outLength;
        NSMutableData * cipherData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:data.length + kCCBlockSizeAES128];
        Byte byte[] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,}; //It`s not valid. The main iv is secret
        NSData *datakey = [NSData dataWithBytes:key.UTF8String length:key.length];
        NSData *datadata = [NSData dataWithBytes:data.UTF8String length:data.length];
        CCCryptorStatus result = CCCrypt( kCCEncrypt
                                        , kCCAlgorithmAES128
                                        , kCCOptionPKCS7Padding
                                        , datakey.bytes
                                        , [datakey length]
                                        , byte
                                        , datadata.bytes
                                        , [datadata length]
                                        , cipherData.mutableBytes
                                        , cipherData.length
                                        , &outLength);
```

`if (result == kCCSuccess) {
        cipherData.length = outLength;
    }
    else {

    }
    NSData *encryptedData=cipherData;
    NSString *str=[encryptedData base64EncodedStringWithOptions: NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
    return str;
}`

Comment: What do you mean that you cant encrypt, what's the error?

Comment: Encrypted string is too short and after that when i decrypt it , data is not complete or is nil

Comment: I bet you have problem with `utf8` irregular bytesize and invalid size of data buffer.

Comment: You are right. But how can i fix it?

Comment: Before encrypting convert to base64.

Comment: If i'm guessing right your problem in `cipherData` creation. Instead of `data.length` use `datadata.length`. That will give you real size for buffer. You should move `datadata` declaration up, ofc.

Comment: @Shebuka No, there is no reason to convert to base64 prior to encryption. Please delete the comment.

Comment: @MehdiGilanpour 1. Provide input and outputs, encrypted outpot should be in hex. 2. The IV does not need to be secret but it does need to be random for each encryption with the same key. The IV can prefix the encrypted data for use during decryption.

Comment: @zaph changing iv for each time does not change anything at the end. The problem is about specific characters.

Comment: @MehdiGilanpour It is just secure practice, generally security is the point of encryption.

Comment: @zaph The key derivation here is so insecure that reusing the IV is hardly the most pressing problem. :D (But also, Zaph is totally right about the IV. This code is just highly insecure in several ways.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `cipherData` is to short. It need to be a block longer than `datadata` which may (such as in this case) be longer than `data.length`.

When creating data with utf-8 encoding from a string that contains multiple-byte data such as Arabic, emoji and etc the data will be longer than the string characters.

Incorrect code:

```
NSMutableData * cipherData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:data.length + kCCBlockSizeAES128];
NSData *datadata = [NSData dataWithBytes:data.UTF8String length:data.length];
```

Correct code:

```
NSData *datadata = [data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableData * cipherData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength: datadata.length + kCCBlockSizeAES128];
```

Note that misnaming the input string `data` does not help, it is a string. renaming `data` -> `tex` and then ``datadata`->`data` makes the code more clear. Good naming solves many code problems.

Comment: Indeed, that what i meant in my comment.

Comment: shouldn't that be `data.UTF8String.length`? Or better, `[data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`?

Comment: @Sulthan There is no `data.UTF8String.length`. (UTF8String is a char*). But yeah, this should be `dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding`. Otherwise you have call `lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:`.

Comment: @RobNapier Oh yes, you are right. Otherwise the string is still truncated.

Comment: `NSData *datadata = [NSData dataWithBytes:data.UTF8String length:data.length];` is wrong because `data.length` is the number of characters in the string, which is smaller than the number of bytes in the UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: It's *possible* that this is exactly the bug that forced me to create RNCryptor v2 in a panic… (OK, in that case for the password rather than the data, and I'm not admitting I made that mistake or anything…)

Comment: My Bad! OK, I see the error, corrected. That is what I get for blindly copying code without really looking.